# How to call new Activity in Custom adapter for recycleview in dropdown menu?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have created `recycleview` which objects have also dropdown menu, on the second item of the dropdown menu I want to call new activity? how do I do that? Thank you

```
 //Calling menu menu_prijem_posiljke to display menu options on click on three dots
        holder.view.img_more.setOnClickListener{
            val popupMenu = PopupMenu(holder.view.context, it ,Gravity.START)
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                when(item.itemId){
                    R.id.storniraj ->{
                        Toast.makeText(holder.view.context,"this is toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        true
                    }
                    R.id.detalji->{
                        Toast.makeText(holder.view.context,"this is toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        true
                    }
                    else -> false
                }
            }
            popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_prijem_posiljke)
            popupMenu.show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can call the `startActivity` from the adapter if you've not passed the context reference in your adapter constructor.

```
holder.view.img_more.context.startActivity(
                            Intent(
                                holder.view.img_more.context,
                                MainActivity::class.java
                            )
                        )
```

And if you have passed the context reference in your adapter reference then you can directly use the context instance instead of **holder.view.img_more.context**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this ...

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.setClass(holder.view.context, MyOtherActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
//end current activity if required
//finish()
```

Comment: I have tried that but

val intent = Intent()
intent.setClass(holder.view.context, MyOtherActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)     <<<---- Here for intent says "Type mismatch. Required context"
//end current activity
finish()

//

Comment: this worked
holder.view.img_more.context.startActivity(
                            Intent(
                                holder.view.img_more.context,
                                MainActivity::class.java
                            )
                        )

and thank you too

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
val intent = Intent(Context, NextClass::class.java)
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent)
```

This sould start the new activity from your `adapter`, You can pass the context of `activity` or `fragment` via constructor.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.item1:
                        //handle item1 click
                        return true;
                    case R.id.item2:
                         view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), ToActivity.class));
                        return true;
                    case R.id.item3:
                        //handle item3 click
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, but this worked for me

holder.view.img_more.context.startActivity(
                            Intent(
                                holder.view.img_more.context,
                                MainActivity::class.java
                            )
                        )

Answer (score 0):

The better way for doing so is to implement the redirection in your Activity and **Not in the adapter**, and you can achieve this by following these steps:

Step 1:
Add a parameter to your adapter called onMenuItemClicked :

```
class YourAdapter(var onMenuItemClicked: (Int) -> Boolean) : RecyclerView.Adapter<Holder>()
```

Step 2:
Change your code to this

```
holder.view.imageViewMore.setOnClickListener {
                val popupMenu = PopupMenu(holder.view.context, it, Gravity.START)
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                    onMenuItemClicked(item.itemId)
                }
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu_prijem_posiljke)
                popupMenu.show()
            }
```

Step 3:
In you activity, initialize the adapter like this:

```
val adapter = YourAdapter {
                    when(itemId){
                        R.id.storniraj ->{
                            Toast.makeText(holder.view.context,"this is toast message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            true
                        }
                        R.id.detalji->{
                            startActivity(this@MainActivity , SecondActivity::class.java)
                            true
                        }
                        else -> false
                    }
                }
```